# Key (0, 0) is not a string when dumping json to a file- python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to dump a dictionary to a json file using the code below:

```
import json
with open('save.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump({
        (0, 0): 0,
        (0, 1): 1,
        (1, 0): 0,
        (1, 1): 1,
    }, outfile)
```

But I'm having an issue with using tuples as keys. This works when I define a dictionary, but when I try to dump it to a file it gives this error:

```
TypeError: key (0, 0) is not a string
```

I'm using Python 3 on a linux based machine.

Any help fixing this would be appreciated.

Comment: How does json look like?

Comment: There is no "fixing this" - JSON object keys are always strings, by definition. Change the tuples to strings, then the error goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON standard **requires** keys being strings.
If your purpose is saving this dictionary into a file - consider using `pickle` module:

```
import pickle
with open('save.json', 'w') as outfile:
    pickle.dump({
        (0, 0): 0,
        (0, 1): 1,
        (1, 0): 0,
        (1, 1): 1,
    }, outfile)
```